# Wildfly 19 - error WFLYCTL0362: Capabilities required by resource

Tags: wildfly, infinispan

I have added a cache-container in the "infinispan" subsystem of WildFly 19 **standalone.xml**,  as follows:

```
        <cache-container name="appCacheContainer" default-cache="passivation">
            <local-cache name="appCache">
                    <!-- expiration, eviction, security... -->
            </local-cache>
        </cache-container>
```

However, when I start the Wildfly, I receive the following error:

```
 00:25:41,885 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0362: Capabilities required by resource '/subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=appCacheContainer' are not available:
org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.cache-configuration.appCacheContainer.passivation; Possible registration points for this capability: 
    /subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=*/local-cache=*
    /subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=*/invalidation-cache=*
    /subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=*/replicated-cache=*
    /subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=*/distributed-cache=*
    /subsystem=infinispan/cache-container=*/scattered-cache=*
00:25:41,893 FATAL [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0056: Server boot has failed in an unrecoverable manner; exiting. See previous messages for details.
```

Did I miss any configuration settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by removing the attribute "default-cache" from the cache-container tag.

Now, my cache-container looks like as follows:

```
    <cache-container name="appCacheContainer">
        <local-cache name="appCache">
                <!-- expiration, eviction, security... -->
        </local-cache>
    </cache-container>
```

However, I am not sure why attribute "default-cache" produced the error.

Comment: By setting default-cache you've asked to get cache called 'passivation' when asking for the default cache, e.g. by calling the parameterless `cacheManager.getCache()`. No cache with this name was defined in the list of caches (the error lists posssible types), though.